# Merge two DataTables to Single DataTable using LINQ, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-3.5

ASP.NET using C#.NET; .NET3.5

I've two datatables as below:

**DataTable1**:

```
Location   Visa_Q1     Visa_Q2
Blore      25          40
Hyd        40          60
```

**DataTable2**:

```
Location   Visa_Q3     Visa_Q4
Blore      50          35
Hyd        80          90
```

How to combine both datatables for getting the output as DataTable as below using `LINQ` (without looping each row):

**CombinedDataTable**:

```
Location   Visa_Q1     Visa_Q2   Visa_Q3    Visa_Q4
Blore      25          40        50         35
Hyd        40          60        80         90
```

**EDIT**:

Just by joining two tables based on matching 'Location' i want the resultant data in combined form. I don't want to select each column field manually as `select new { .... };`

Comment: Do your requirements say that loops are forbidden?

Comment: We are in consistent to use loops as minimum as possible due to the peformance requirement. So i need with LINQ

Comment: Where are you getting the `DataTables` from? You'll need to modify that code if you want to avoid looping - LINQ to Objects just uses loops internally.

Comment: I'm filling the datatables using SQLDataAdapter from Database.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var results = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on table1["Location"] equals table2["Location"]
              select new
                  {
                      Location = table1["Location"],
                      Visa_Q1 = (int)table1["Visa_Q1"],
                      Visa_Q2 = (int)table1["Visa_Q2"],
                      Visa_Q3 = (int)table2["Visa_Q3"],
                      Visa_Q4 = (int)table2["Visa_Q4"],
                  };
```

**Edit**

try this for select all columns

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataColumn column in t1.Columns)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
        }

        foreach (DataColumn column in t2.Columns)
        {
            if (column.ColumnName == "Location")
                table.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName + "2", column.DataType);
            else
                table.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);
        }

        var results = t1.AsEnumerable().Join(t2.AsEnumerable(),
                a => a.Field<String>("Location"),
                b => b.Field<String>("Location"),
                (a, b) =>
                {
                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = a.ItemArray.Concat(b.ItemArray).ToArray();
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                    return row;
                });
```

Comment: If there are 'n' no of columns which are dynamic(NOT static). do i need manually select each column field from each table? How can i get the result in this scenario

Comment: Just by joining two tables based on matching 'Location' i want the resultant data in combined form. I don't want to select each column field manually as you mentioned above in `select new { .... };`

Comment: Getting Exception:
`System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."
  Source="System.Data"`

Comment: I'm getting the above said exception when i try to do this statement:

`table = results.CopyToDataTable();`

Comment: @sukumar Why are you copying results to datatable? In the second solution above, the result will be kept in `table` (which you need to declare first btw).

Comment: @Ole_Brun: I couldn't get with your comment. Please can elaborate the same.

Comment: @sukumar In the second example, you can see that `row` is put into ` table`. This row will be a concatenation of data in dt1 and dt2. So if you create the table first with `var table = new DataTable()`, you will get the result already contained in `table`. If you want to use `CopyToDataTable`, you will need a new fresh table that does not contain any data.

Comment: @Ole_Brun: Surprise to see that the resultant `table` contains nothing. There is no data at `table` DataTable. It's totally empty. Neither Rows or columns found. Seems something wrong using the code (second example). Kindly check/verify once at your end.

Comment: I know it has one extra column but you can easily remove it after getting results.

Comment: In the Datatable `table`, i'm getting only column fields but still there is no data in that. After the last step `results` anything else do i need to do?? Please validate the same once again. Still i didn't find any data or rows in `table`. Only column headers are displayed.

Comment: After the last step `results` anything else do i need to do??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> res = 
    from d1 in DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
    join d2 in DataTable2.AsEnumerable() on d1["Location"] equals d2["Location"]
    select new DataRow
    {
        d1["Location"],
        d1["Visa_Q1"],
        d1["Visa_Q2"],
        d2["Visa_Q3"],
        d2["Visa_Q4"]
    };

DataTable CombinedDataTable = res.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: How can i get the above resultant combined DataTable without selecting individual column fields like Visa_Q1,Q2...etc manually

Comment: Just by joining two tables based on matching 'Location' i want the resultant data in combined form. I don't want to select each column field manually as you mentioned above in `select new { .... };`

Comment: I don't know of any Linq-way of doing this, so I guess you have to add some logic within the new-clause to do the combining stuff, like @HarisHasan is suggesting.