# Merge two DataTables with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datatable, dataset

My question is similar too [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777595/merge-two-datatables-to-single-datatable-using-linq-c-sharp)

I have two DataTables:

**DataTable 1:**

```
Column 1: Date
Column 2: Requests 1
```

**DataTable 2:**

```
Column 1: Date
Column 2: Requests 2
```

I need the bellow result:

**New DataTable:**

```
Column 1: Date
Column 2: Requests 1
Column 3: Requests 2
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Date            Requests 1  Requests 2    Total
15/08/2013      25          40            60
14/08/2013      40          60            100
13/08/2013      40          0             25
12/08/2013      0           80            80
```

What I did until now:

```
DataTable Lista_1 = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable Lista_2 = ds.Tables[1];

var myLINQ = from l1 in Lista_1.AsEnumerable()
             join l2 in Lista_2.AsEnumerable() 
             on l1.Field<DateTime>("Date") equals l2.Field<DateTime>("Date")
             select new
             {
                 dateRelatorio = l1.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                 request1Relatorio = l1.Field<int>("Total"),
                 request2Relatorio = l2.Field<int>("contagem"),
                 total = l1.Field<int>("Total") + l2.Field<int>("contagem")
             };
```

And I would like to return an IList collection (System.Collections.IList)

**UPDATE**

```
listReturn = new List<Stats>();
public class Stats
{
public DateTime dateRelatorio { get; set; }
public int request1Relatorio { get; set; }
public int request2Relatorio { get; set; }
public int total { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

May have dates in List_1 that there is not in List_2 and vice versa, so the Request need to be 0.

Comment: The code seems fine, just add `.ToList()`

Comment: An `Ilist<OfWhat>`? You cannot return an anonymous type from the method.

Comment: What if there 3 rows with date `15/08/2013` in first table and two rows with same date in second table? You need 6 rows in result table?

Comment: To use `LINQ to DataSet`, you must convert it to `Enumerable stuff`, but to get back a `DataTable` as far as I know you must use `CopyToDataTable()`, but this method doesn't seem to support anonymous type (with 3 columns as properties). I don't think you can solve this using `LINQ`.

Comment: @KingKing: `CopyToDataTable` works only with `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. However, you can make it work with anything with the help of reflection(which is not efficient): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The date will not repeat, because I did a group by on sql server. But the List_1 could be dates that there is not in List_2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this thing to be encapsulated in a method, you should create a class to be returned:

```
public class DailyReport
{
  public DateTime Date {get; set;}
  public int Requests1 {get; set;}
  public int Requests2 {get; set;}
  public int Total // this can be calculated on the fly
  {
    get {return Requests1 + Requests2; }
  }
}
```

And then do

```
public List<DailyReport> GetDailyReports(..parameters if needed...)
{
  ...
  var myLINQ = from ...
         select new DailyReport {
             Date = l1.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
             Requests1 = l1.Field<int>("Total"),
             Requests2 = l2.Field<int>("contagem"),
         };
  return myLINQ.ToList();
}
```

There are some dirty hacks that could enable you to return an collection of anonymous objects, but I would advise against it.

Comment: We are almost there. I have just one issue. When the List_1 have a Date there is not in the List_2 the Request in the List_2 need to be 0 and vice versa like my Expected Result.