# Combine two non-identical rows of a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, merge, datatables

I have two datatables dt1 and dt2 ,where as dt1 contains of a single column "ID" and dt2 contains of a single column "NAME". My requirement is to combine both the datatables and create a new datatable (ie)

[image]

whereas as mentioned above i need to get the datas of both the datatable **(dt1 & dt2 )** and need to  create a new **datatable**.

---

Comment: **Any attempt?** It may save us to rewrite code you already produced...

Comment: I dunno who gave down vote , Sorry for that fellow who cannot able to understand my question :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two DataTables to Single DataTable using LINQ, C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777595/merge-two-datatables-to-single-datatable-using-linq-c-sharp)

Comment: _Problem_ isn't your question is not clear. Problem is you posted your requirement but you didn't show any effort to first solve problem by yourself. I don't doubt you tried but if you don't show it...we may even think it's another question from an help vampire...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

dt1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
dt2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
dr["id"] = 1;
dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt1.NewRow();
dr["id"] = 2;
dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt2.NewRow();
dr["name"] = "XXX";
dt2.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt2.NewRow();
dr["name"] = "YYY";
dt2.Rows.Add(dr);

DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
dt3.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
dt3.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dr = dt3.NewRow();

    dr["id"] = dt1.Rows[i]["id"];
    dr["name"] = dt2.Rows[i]["name"];
    dt3.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to combine to DataTables, you can do the following:

```
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Items");
        DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn("id", typeof(System.Int32));
        table1.Columns.Add(column1);

        DataTable table2 = new DataTable("details");
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String));
        table1.Columns.Add(column);

        table1.Merge(table2); //table1 will have 2 columns after executing this line
```